# How to fix "TypeError: record.Recording is not a function" in "node-record-lpcm16" library

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am following the example ( https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-nodejs) but I am getting this error when runing `node index.js`

```
$ node index.js
C:\Users\mysti\Desktop\TransREACH\index.js:38
record.Recording()
   ^

TypeError: record.Recording is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> 
       (C:\Users\mysti\Desktop\TransREACH\index.js:38:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
        (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

I am using windows 10, and node-record-lpcm16 version 1.0.1 (i think).

How would I call the start function without getting this error?

Comment: Have you properly installed [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) for Windows as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-nodejs)?

Comment: I believe so, when I look into the node module there isn't a record.Recording function